Is $X\times\{0\}\cup X\times \{1\}$ diffeomorphic to $X$?
Given $X$ a $n$-differentiable manifold such $\partial X=\varnothing$, prove there exists $Y$ a $n+1$-differentiable manifold with frontier, such $\partial Y$ is diffeomorphic to $X$.
My attemp: Let be $Y:=X\times[0,1]$. This is cleary a $n+1$-differentiable manifold with frontier and:
$$\partial Y=\partial(X\times [0,1])=X\times \partial[0,1]=X\times \{0,1\}=(X\times \{0\})\cup(X\times \{1\})$$
So now how to prove that $\partial Y$ is diffeomorphic to $X$? I was thinking in consider the map $\varphi:X_{0}\cup X_{1}\to X$ such $\varphi(x,t)=x$. But it has maybe no inverse so I don't know how to proced.

Notice that $\partial Y$ cannot (always) be diffeomorphic to $X$ (or, at least \textit{a priori} not from the usual map of forgetting the time component) being equal to $2$ copies (so it isnt even bijective).
The notion you are referring to is the property of "null-bordand". From Poincare duality one obtains that an obstruction to this property is the Euler characteristic: if $\chi(M)$ is odd then $M$ cannot be null-bordant.

$X\times {0,1}$ is not connected, so it is not a manifold. Diffeomorphisms only apply to differentiable manifolds.

$X$ is a manifold contain in some $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Being contained in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a strong hypothesis: by Whitney's embedding theorem all manifold can be embedded.

Oh, I get it, $\partial Y$ is not a manifold. So I have to think in another $Y$ or this is just false?

If $X=[0,1]$ then $Y$ is a square whose boundary is not $X\times {0,1}$

I mean, if you don't have some additional requirement, $Y=[0.1)\times X$ seems to work.

The claim is that there exists a $Y$ with the desired property, not that every $Y$ has the property. You made a choice of $Y$ which didn't have the desired property, so you need to make a different choice.

Where did this claim come from? There are topological obstructions to having $X$ be the boundary of some manifold with boundary, as @Alessandro already indicated.
